# ConcurrentQueue<T> or Queue<T> when one thread only ever enqueues and another thread only ever dequeues

Tags: c#, multithreading, queue, fifo

I have a FIFO and two threads. One thread will only ever enqueue to the FIFO and the other thread will only ever dequeue from the FIFO. Do I need to take the  ConcurrentQueue or is the Queue enough?

Comment: Did you read the docs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/when-to-use-a-thread-safe-collection#concurrentqueuet-vs-queuet Can you clarify where your confusion lies?

Comment: My confusion was that I thought it might still be possible to use Queue<T> as long as you make sure only one thread operates on each side of the FIFO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, you still require a thread-safe solution - even if there's only one writer thread and one reader thread.

It would be easier to use the ConcurrentQueue. You could use Queue instead if you wanted to, but you would have to do the locking yourself.

Comment: What's the long answer?

Answer (score 10):

If you have more than one thread, it will require thread safety and synchronization for your `Queue` object instance. In order to avoid reinventing the wheel and doing it yourself, I would suggest using Microsoft's `ConcurrentQueue`.

MSDN:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.queue?view=netframework-4.7.1

> Use ConcurrentQueue or ConcurrentStack if you need to access the
>   collection from multiple threads concurrently.

If you use a `Queue` ( i.e., not the `ConcurrentQueue`) with more than one thread updating the object instance, you could encounter run time exceptions, such as:

- ArgumentOutOfRangeException
- ArgumentException ( InvalidOffLen)
- ExceptionResource.InvalidOperation_EmptyQueue

The exceptions are possible if the Queue's internal state is being modified but not yet completed due to CPU thread scheduling. If another thread accesses the Queue object instance while it's in an inconsistent state, you could and probably will encounter these exceptions.

Source Code to review:

.Net Framework 4.7.1
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/queue.cs

**Sample Console Application:**

Run the following as your lab and you should encounter a System.InvalidOperationException

**System.InvalidOperationException: 'Collection was modified after the enumerator was instantiated.'**

```
class Program
{
    static Queue<string> Queue = new Queue<string>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread producer = new Thread(Enqueue);
        Thread consumer = new Thread(Dequeue);

        producer.Start();
        consumer.Start();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void Enqueue()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            Queue.Enqueue("Number : " + i);
            SimulateWork();
        }
    }

    static void Dequeue()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (Queue.Any())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Queue.Dequeue());
                SimulateWork();
            }
        }
    }

    static void SimulateWork()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        { }
    }
}
```

This lab demonstrates what can happen when an `Queue` instance is accessed while in an inconsistent state. Even with just one producer and one consumer you need proper synchronization.

If you add locking or synchronization around the `Enqueue` and `Dequeue` operations, you will notice it runs without issue.

```
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                Queue.Enqueue("Number : " + i);
                SimulateWork();
            }


            lock (lockObject)
            {
                if (Queue.Any())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Queue.Dequeue());
                    SimulateWork();
                }
            }
```

With that being said, I am **NOT** suggesting that you manually add locks that will block. This is more of a lab exercise to help you understand the **WHY**.

Microsoft has invested a lot of time in providing us thread safe collections like the `ConcurrentQueue` using fine-grained locking and lock-free mechanisms.

> Some of the concurrent collection types use lightweight
>   synchronization mechanisms such as SpinLock, SpinWait, SemaphoreSlim,
>   and CountdownEvent, which are new in the .NET Framework 4. These
>   synchronization types typically use busy spinning for brief periods
>   before they put the thread into a true Wait state. When wait times are
>   expected to be very short, spinning is far less computationally
>   expensive than waiting, which involves an expensive kernel transition.
>   For collection classes that use spinning, this efficiency means that
>   multiple threads can add and remove items at a very high rate. For
>   more information about spinning vs. blocking, see SpinLock and
>   SpinWait.

As stated above, if you have more than one thread, it will require thread safety and synchronization for your `Queue` object instance. In order to avoid reinventing the wheel and doing it yourself, I would **highly** suggest using Microsoft's `ConcurrentQueue`.

**References:**

Thread Safe Collections:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/

Lock Keyword

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

Threading:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/threading/index